# Wildfly 8 is cutting off cookie value

Tags: rest, cookies, jboss7.x, wildfly

We have an application we are moving off of Glassfish 3 to Wildfly 8.

When we login to the application, we make a REST request to authenticate the login, which assigned a serialized object  in the cookies. The Then we take the cookies and make another REST request to authorize the user.

This works fine in Glassfish. In Wildfly, it cuts off the serialized object -- only about 20 of the 100+ characters are passed to the second service. We didn't change any code when we moved over.

Anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it -- upgrade to 8.0.1 (which is nightly now) and  `allow-equals-in-cookie-value="true"` in the default http listener tag.